# how to change text case using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I feel like a fool, couldn't figure out how to change case using jQuery. 
Stackoverflow = stackoverflow.

jQuery

```
 var name = "Stackoverflow"
 $('name').toLowerCase();
 alert(name);
```

Comment: It may be worth [learning JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/) before trying to pick up jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need JQuery for this. Just use pure JavaScript:

```
var name = "Stackoverflow"
name = name.toLowerCase();
alert(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var name = "Stackoverflow"
name.toLowerCase();
alert(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a variable, `name`, and then trying to use jQuery to reference it as an object, which is incorrect as it is not a valid object.  Instead, you want to apply the JavaScript method `toLowerCase()` to the variable and that will convert the string as desired.

```
var name = "Stackoverflow"
name = name.toLowerCase();
alert(name);
```

In order to use the method on an actual object, you would first have to extract a string value from that object, likely utilizing either the `text()` or `val()` methods, before applying the case conversion method.

You can make it simpler by applying the `toLowerCase()` method directly to the string in the variable declaration as follows:

```
var name = "Stackoverflow".toLowerCase();
alert(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this. JavaScript has toLowerCase and toUpperCase functions already built in to the String class.